# DACPAC Deployment in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-sql-database, dacpac

I want to create a dacpac file using VSTS. If I create a dacpac file and commit in VSTS to execute the scripts using **Execute Azure SQL Tak:Dacpactask** Azure database, we are unable to maintain the history of the changes. So I want to make the changes in SQL Project and move the project to VSTS. **Do we have any task/way to generate a DACPAC file using sql project that we have in VSTS?.** Finally I want to call that dacpac file using  **Execute Azure SQL Tak:Dacpactask** to execute the scripts in Azure database

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to these steps below:

1. Refer to Grant’s answer to add project (not dacpac file) to source control and track changes
2. Create a new build definition
3. Add **NuGet Tool Installer** task (Version of NuGet.exe to install: `4.3.0`)
4. Add **NuGet** task (Version:`2.*`; Command: `restore`; Path to solution, packages.config, or project.json: `**/*sln`)
5. Add **Visual Studio Build** task (Solution: `[click … to select solution file]`; Visual Studio Version: `Visual Studio 2015`; MSBuild Arguments: `/p:OutDir=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`)
6. Add Azure SQL Database Deployment task: (DACPAC File: `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\**\SQLDatabase.dacpac`)

Answer (score 0):

In order to track changes you just have to connect your database project to whatever source control system you're using. It's a fundamental part of Visual Studio. You can just do that. Once it's connected to source control, you can then automate builds from the source control system using all the other Visual Studio tools. [Here's an example that seems fairly complete](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-database-source-control-using-visual-studio-online-git/). The next step is to integrate through the deployment processes in VSTS to automate the whole thing.